# Sometimes the system boots slow

Tags: boot

Brand new computer with SSD and most of the times the system boots really fast, but other times it doesn't. I enter my password and then wait solid minute and a half. I tried to see if there is any pattern, but I am not doing anything specific at those times. DO you have any idea what could be causing the issue ? Is there a way for me to check why it boots so slow ? (preferably using tools that are already in the system and no installation is needed)

EDIT :

After I ran the command suggested by the accepted answer I got the following info :

The kernel is booting from 0 to 2.5 secs

The rest of the files are booting from 2.5 to 3.2 secs

Something called ureadahead.service is deactivating for solid 8 seconds. What could be the cause ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Intel Graphics that was a bug and it was solved already so doing `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` is going to fix it.

To check your boot time you can use `systemd-analyze`.
To know what is making your boot time slow, use instead `systemd-analyze critical-chain`. The ones that appear in red are holding up your boot.

Lastly you can use `systemd-analyze plot > boot` to create a file inside your home directory and check all packages involved in your boot.

---

NOTE: This only works on Loki or newer.

Comment: I am actually using Nvidia card with Intel processor. can the bug mentioned by you still appear ? I tried updating the system, but the issue is still here.

Comment: Yes it can also happen. I have a similar setup and my problem was fixed a while ago.

Comment: I understand, I just tried to upgrade the distro again and found only dependencies to be removed. Will check the next boot :)

Comment: I have AMD Graphics and I guess it's the same bug. I've noticed it happening after some updates then it goes away, and it's also happening to me now, after the last updates. It might have been reported, I didn't check.

Comment: Hey, do you mind taking a look at the edit info ?

Comment: What edit? I dont see any

Nevermind, I thought you meant a edit in my answer

Comment: Try masking it:  `sudo systemctl mask ureadahead.service` That service read files in advance to supposedly improve boot time. You could see if there's a big file it shouldn't be reading and delete it: `systemctl status -l ureadahead.service`

Comment: But make sure it's not an important file! Or it may cause more problems

Comment: i should do it now ? I mean not right after the boot, but I can just copy the commands now ?

Comment: Yes, do it now. but try the second command first.

Comment: sorry for the late response! It gives me warning that the list might be incomplete and it shows only these two  : 1. /lib/modprobe.d/blacklist_linux_4.4.0-47-generic.co ; 2. /var/lib/lightdm-data/hroom/wallpaper/Photo by Spa

Comment: So i rebooted after using the first command and it booted fast, but when i used the second again it did not show anything. Just ''Warning: ureadahead.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.'' Is this normal ?

Comment: Yes. With the first command it kinda disables the service so it boots faster. If you happen to have any error at boot (errors not warnings) then tell me, otherwise problem solved!